# Small Python ord() script

Tags: python, ord

I have a text file with a Chinese character [x3400-9FFF] at the beginning of each line.  I'd like to replace it with its code in decimal (not hex), without affecting the rest of the file, which is ASCII.

It should be super easy using the ord() function in Python, right?  I just don't know any Python.  Here's what I've written:

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

#converts Chinese to decimal

class HanCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def replaceHanzi(self, edit, text):
        return re.sub(r'([\x3400-\x9FFF])', ord())
    def run(self, edit):
        self.replaceHanzi(edit, text)
```

Answer (score 0):

try using the `replace()` function:

```
s = "א aaaaabbb" 
s = s.replace(u"א", str(ord(u"א")))
print(s)
```

output:

```
1488 aaaaabbb
```

1488 is the unicode value of this letter in base 10.

also, notice that in

`def replaceHanzi(self, edit, text):
     return re.sub(r'([\x3400-\x9FFF])', ord())`
you don't use `edit` and `text`. You should use them as follows:

```
def replaceHanzi(self, edit, text):
    return text.replace(edit, str(ord(edit)))
```